# Почему при запуске бота Telegram выскакивает UnicodeDecodeError в python?

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Я решил создать бота для Telegram, и начал тренироваться. Я написал вот этот код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот для заказов иллюстраций.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

но у меня выскакивает огромная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TelegramBot\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 664, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 726, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 686, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\TelegramBot\main.py", line 9, in welcome
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1219, in send_sticker
    apihelper.send_data(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 868, in send_data
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, files=files, method='post')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 151, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
  File "C:\Users\Федя\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Федя\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\Федя\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 319, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Users\Федя\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 512, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\Users\Федя\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 159, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 32: character maps to <undefined>
```

Можете подсказать, почему *(прошу пишите сразу ответы, если не просите что-то)*.

Comment: Потому что вы пытаетесь открыть файл в текстовом режиме, в то время как webp не является текстовым форматом

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!